# Why not working check checkbox?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test1" class="check" checked="">
<input type="checkbox" id="test2" class="check" checked="">
<input type="checkbox" id="test3" class="check" checked="">
<input type="checkbox" id="test4" class="check" checked="">

    <button class="start">Click</button>

$(".start").click(function(){

alert($("#test1").attr("checked"));

});
```

Why if i delete check on checkbox **test1** `alert` show **checked** ?

Test on JsFiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/A6Sdq/)**

Comment: Not sure, but try using `$("#test1:checked").length` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

The pertinent part:

```
elem.checked                     true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state
$(elem).prop("checked")       true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state
elem.getAttribute("checked")      "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change
$(elem).attr("checked") (1.6)     "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change
$(elem).attr("checked") (1.6.1+)  "checked" (String) Will change with checkbox state
$(elem).attr("checked") (pre-1.6) true (Boolean) Changed with checkbox state
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the alert if the check box is checked use this:

```
if ($("#test1").is(':checked') ) {alert("yes")}
```

Example [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/awEf7/)

```
$(".start").click(function(){
   if ($("#test1").is(':checked') ) {alert("yes")}    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is because you are testing the static HTML.

If you want to test the *checked* property use instead

```
alert($("#test1").prop("checked"));
```

This gives you either `true`or `false`

BTW: the attribute should be either `checked="checked"` or not present at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing `.attr` and `.prop`. Here you should be using `.prop`:

```
alert($("#test1").prop("checked"));
```

An `attribute` of an element is something it that is set by the markup - you can't change it. A `property` reflects the state of it now. There was some confusion in the implementation in earlier versions of jQuery which has now been resolved. As a result some online resources still have it wrong.